# Problem using a proxy while running a Python script

Tags: python, proxy, biopython, blast

I'm having a problem related to proxies in my Python script. Running the script below, to access NCBI Blast through biopython, the company's network where I work blocks the access because of security reasons. While talking with the IT guys they gave me a proxy for this kind of situations that has to be incorporated in my script. I've tried a lot of potential solutions but nothing seems to be working. Am I missing something here?

```
def main(seq):
    import os
    from Bio.Blast import NCBIWWW
    import time
    start_time = time.time()
    try:
        print('Connecting to NCBI...')
        blast_handle = NCBIWWW.qblast('blastn','nt',sequence = seq, format_type = 'Text', megablast=True)
        text = blast_handle.read()
        print(text)
        print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import os
    os.environ['http_proxy'] = 'http://123.456.78.90:80' # The proxy IT guys gave me

    seq = 'CAACTTTTTTTTTTATTACAGACAATCAAGAAATTTTCTATTGAAATAAAATATTTTAAA\
           ACTTTCAACAACGGATCTCTTGGTTCTCGCATCGATGAAGAACGTAGCGAATTGCGATAA\
           GTAATGTGAATTGCAGATTCTCGTGAATCATTGAATTTTTGAACGCACATTGCGCCCTCT\
           GGTATTCCAGAGGGCATGCCTGTTTGAGCGTCATTTCCTTCTCAAAAACCCAGTTTTTGG\
           TTGTGAGTGATACTCTGCTTCAGGGTTAACTTGAAAATGCTATGCCCCTTTGGCTGCCCT\
           TCTTTGAGGGGACTGCGCGTCTGTGCAGGATGTAACCAATGTATTTAGGTATTCATACCA\
           ACTTTCATTGTGCGCGTCTTATGCAGTTGTAGTCCACCCAACCTCAGACACACAGGCTGG\
           CTGGGCCAACAGTATTCATAAAGTTTGACCTCA'
    main(seq)
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: The request might be https? Try setting the `https_proxy` environment variable to the same proxy

Comment: @IainShelvington I've tried that too, won't work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `NCBIWWW.qblast` doesn't have support for proxies, so you will need to adapt the code yourself.

In your local BioPython installation, go find the `biopython/Bio/Blast/NCBIWWW.py` file and add your proxy settings at line 203:

```
request = Request(url_base, message, {"User-Agent": "BiopythonClient"})
request.set_proxy('http://123.456.78.90:80', 'http') # <-- Add this line
handle = urlopen(request)
```